# ripple drawable crashes the app on Android API 19

Tags: android, rippledrawable, android-api-levels

I am using a custom ripple `drawable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:color="@android:color/white">

   <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
   </item>


</ripple>
```

but it crashes the app on API 19

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res / drawable /
    ripple_effect_square2.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02017d
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2101)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:15303)

Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line # 2: invalid drawable tag ripple
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java: 933)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java: 877)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java: 2097)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java: 700) 
at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java: 15303)
```

What should i do to prevent crashing ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [RippleDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html) was added in API 21, so it's not available on earlier SDKs.

You can move your drawable file to **res/drawable-v21** to ensure it doesn't crash on earlier releases.

Comment: is there any alternative ways to do this on pre 21

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem.

**[Mina Samy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235123/mina-samy)'s** answer solved my problem also.

**[Atef Hares](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5993410/atef-hares)** asked for an alternative in older versions.
What works for me is to use a selector instead of ripple

for example:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ccffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/playColor" />
</selector>
```

where

```
<color name="playColor">#E8EAF6</color>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ripple is only available from Lollipop (Android API 21). Here is an example for backwards compatibility which includes states and no default background (Transparent):

Create two drawable `xml` files with the same name, one will be placed in the `drawable-v21` folder, and the other in the normal `drawable` folder.

`drawable-v21/ripple_red_solid.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/red">

    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <color android:color="@android:color/red" />
    </item>

    <item>
        <selector>
            <item android:state_selected="true">
                <color android:color="@android:color/red" />
            </item>
            <item android:state_activated="true">
                <color android:color="@android:color/red" />
            </item>
            <item android:state_focused="true">
                <color android:color="@android:color/red" />
            </item>
        </selector>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

`drawable/ripple_red_solid.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/red" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/red" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/red" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And then simply use it on the view like:

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_red_solid" />
```