# android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-4.4-kitkat

First my target API was 22 (Android L). Everything was worked fine until I lowered my target API to 19 for supporting Android 4.4 (Kitkat). Now I am getting this weird error. The App don´t crashes but only some normal buttons are disappearing.
I am setting my layout via a XML file and via code.
**Error**

> Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering

Does anyone know what causes this error? How can I solve it?

My dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
```

**Update:**
I moved every Vector File to the new drwabale-v21 folder. Now I am getting this error.:

> Android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>                                                                      at                                                                at

....

Unfortunately Android 4.4 doesn´t have support for vector drawables.
What can I do you support vector drawables for => Android 4.4?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35908070/1222099 The issue is that you need to return a Drawable instead of a RippleDrawable in getPressedColorRippleDrawable. Otherwise, on pre-lollipop devices, you will get a VerifyError.

Comment: This is a different problem because I am setting my Layout via a XML file not via Code. And my App doesn´t crash.

Comment: What about creating and inflating two different layouts?

Comment: As you can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37108798/1222099) did you use the support library 22.1 with DrawableCompat?

Comment: `'compile com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'`                         compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'`

Comment: I found [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38814018/1222099). Tell me if it works. =)

Comment: Thank for your help @MachoProgrammer unfortunately I have a new error.

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same problem for past 2 hours. Thanks to Dominic's comment and the [Android Packages Page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html) that helped me find the below lines to solve it

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0'
```